# Phonegap Save captured image in www directory

Tags: android, cordova

I am new in phonegap,I am making an app for android slide view using phonegap. I wants to capture images from camera then save these image files in to "assets/www/images" folder.
Is there any way to do this task. Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u show what have u done so far

Answer (score 2):

Ho Ajay,

welcome to phonegap.

No you cannot modify the content of the `www`folder.

But you can store files (e.g. taken by camera) with the [FileApi](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) on the devices storage.

Using `FileTransfer` you can even upload this image to your server (see [here, the full example has even already the code for taking a picture included](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer)).

Keep in mind that you have to add both plugins (`camera` and `file` / `file-transfer`).

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for help and give the direction

Comment: Hi Sebastian is any way to get back my captured image form sd card please suggest me.

Comment: Of course, if you know the URI you can do anything with that (like Moving, uploading, deleting, ...) What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on the requirements of your app, but you can take a picture using the Cordova Camera API and save the picture to the device's storage:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(
    function (uri) {
        // img.src = uri;
    },
    function (e) {
        // appropriate error handling
    },
    {
        quality : 75,
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit : false,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    }
);
```

If you need to take an arbitrary amount of photos, then in your `success` function you could code some logic which creates an `<img>` tag, and set the src to your uri returned parameter.

More info on the Cordova Camera API can be found here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html.